# spring.datasource.url not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have created one spring boot application, I do not want to keep datasource information in application.properties file as this information will keep on changing. So, All data source information have mentioned in external .txt file. This file is placed outside of project. I am reading this file programmatically. Here is the code,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplicationLuncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
              
        Properties mainProperties = new Properties();
    
        mainProperties.load(new FileInputStream("dbconnection.txt"));          

        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplicationLuncher.class,args);
    }
```

file dbconnection.txt is having below information.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<ip address>:3306/<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
```

When i execute the application, I am getting an error,

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You don't use `mainProperties` for anything, so what relevance do you believe those 2 statements have? Why do you believe that? --- Why not put the properties into the `application.properties` file that is automatically loaded by Spring Boot?

Comment: If you have an extra property file that you want Spring Boot to load, use `@PropertySource` to get it loaded. --- Read the [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) chapter of the [Spring Boot Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/index.html) to learn more about where Spring Boot resolves properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `mainProperties` into Spring Boot application, you can use `SpringApplicationBuilder` for this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplicationLuncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties mainProperties = new Properties();
        mainProperties.load(new FileInputStream("dbconnection.txt"));

        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .sources(SpringBootApplicationLuncher.class)
            .properties(mainProperties)
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

However Spring Boot already provides a way to externiliaze your configuration, check this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) for more details